# I am good at maths and science and **is/am** able to converse in Chinese

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> I am good at maths and science and **is/am** able to converse in Chinese.

Which is more proper to use in this context, is or am? What is the difference between the two in this context?

Comment: Be aware also that math or maths is a dialect difference between American and English http://www.dailywritingtips.com/math-or-maths/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the subject is "I" for both verbs, so the correct form is "am"

> I am good at maths and science and am able to converse in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

If you have difficulties with using multiple forms in one sentence, I'd advice you to split them in two seperate sentences.

> I am good at maths and science.

*and*

> I am able to converse in Chinese.

An other way to discover the right form is by placing the original subject *("I")* back.

> I am good at maths and science and **I** am able to converse in Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply to omit both

> I am good at maths and science and able to converse in Chinese.